# Is linear map f * f = f injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let's say that $V$ is Vector Space and $f : V \to V$ is linear map with $f \circ f=f$

I have to define what is $ker(f)$ of this function.

Can we say that this function is also injective and so $ker(f) = {0} $?

Comment: $f:V\rightarrow V,~v\mapsto 0$

Comment: Consider the map $f: V \rightarrow V$ defined as $f \left( v \right) = 0$ for all $v \in V$. Then, this map is not injective but is involutive.

Comment: Take $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f(x,y)=(x,0)$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $f$ injective and $f \circ f=f$ iff $f=\text{id}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f\circ f = f$, then
$$
f^2 - f = f(Id-f)=0.
$$
Hence, $im(Id-f) \subset \ker f$. If $x\in \ker f$ then
$$
(Id-f)x = x,
$$
so $x\in im(Id-f)$, and we find
$$
im(Id-f) = \ker f.
$$

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot, since the null function is a non-injective function for which that propery holds.

Answer (score -1):

If f•f=f and f is a linear transformation then there are two possibilities for f, either f is zero transformation or identity transformation.
If f is zero transformation then it is not injective and Ker(f)=V.
If f is an identity transformation then it is one one and ker(f)={0}.

Comment: The first sentence is false.